# AS3 - Show splash screen until all is code is loaded

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am developing an adobe air mobile app and after I launch it, if I click the buttons right away, the sound does not play. If I wait a few seconds, the buttons function normally. How do I have a movie clip/splash screen show on top until all is loaded so I don't have this problem? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your sounds embedded in the app or are you loading them at runtime? I assume embedded, but in that case it shouldn't take time before they are available.

If loading sounds at runtime, just respond to Event.COMPLETE to hide your splash screen. Or use setTimeout with a suitable delay if you have no events to respond to:

```
//wait 5000ms
setTimeout(hideSplashScreenFunction, 5000);
....
function hideSplashScreen():void
{
    //hide splash screen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `splashScreenMinimumDisplayTime`property you can achieve. Like this

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
            splashScreenImage="@Embed('assets/icons/chrome/logo.png')"
            splashScreenMinimumDisplayTime="4000" splashScreenScaleMode="none">
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Raja, but I am using Flash CS6 to develop. Not Flex.